# How to retrieve Device ID from Microsoft Authenticator App(MSAL) in Android?

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-msal, adal

I am new to Android and as well MSAL. So do forgive me, if I have missed some obvious documentation. However, so far I could not find any documentation on how to do the following :

How to get the Device ID from Microsoft Authenticator app using another Android app(built on MSAL-Android SDK)? The device has completed Azure Device registration via Microsoft Authenticator App(**this device registration id is also then visible in Azure portal**).

Any points on how to get it?
The only reason for my confidence on this being possible, is because of the following two GitHub issue :

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/1204

> Sometimes using MSAL we are not able to retrieve the device ID with device ID claim from authenticator Application, though the device got registered it Azure AD successfully and shows correctly in Authenticator app as well as on azure portal.
> After cleaning/removing accounts in Authenticator(Registration not removed), Tried the fetch the Device ID again using claim, it was successful.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/883